# Prevent PHPMailer from activating links it sends?

Tags: php, phpmailer

I'm working on an application that uses PHPMailer to build and send activation links. For some reason, PHPMailer seems to be opening/visiting the links that it sends in the process of building them. This leads every user to be activated whether the email is delivered or not.

At first I thought it was an issue with the way the verification function was set up, but I've found that if I break the link that PHPMailer sends (by inserting a character that makes it invalid or removing the message body entirely), users are not activated prematurely. Of course, this makes the link that they receive useless.

Here is how the mail is being built:

```
$mail->From = EMAIL_VERIFICATION_FROM_EMAIL;
    $mail->FromName = EMAIL_VERIFICATION_FROM_NAME;
    $mail->AddAddress($user_email);
    $mail->Subject = EMAIL_VERIFICATION_SUBJECT;
    mail->Body = EMAIL_VERIFICATION_CONTENT . EMAIL_VERIFICATION_URL . '/' . urlencode($user_id) .    '/' . urlencode($user_activation_hash);
```

Is the approach here correct? Or is there something strange going on that I've overlooked?

Comment: Why don't you check the access logs on the webserver to see the host that's making the request?  I doubt it's the PHPMailer stuff, more likely the recipient of the email is hitting those links for some reason.

Comment: Yep, it's not PHPMailer doing this but something at the recipient end. It's quite common for spam/malware checkers to check links before passing messages on to inboxes. I've seen Symantec's filters do it.

Comment: You guys had it– hosts's spam filter was rifling through everything. Probably going to move to a bulk mailer. Thank you all!